# Not returning string properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a string in my database saved as "`Utført`" but when I try to return it it gets messed up when I do

```
return dd($finito);
```

[image]

Comment: What's the table collation?

Comment: The collation doesn't really matter, that just affects sorting. But the encoding of the database, the string before it was put in, the page it's being displayed on, etc., definitely matter. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html is probably a good thing to read before proceeding.

Comment: if you use dd(), you don't have an UTF-8 output. that make your special characters look out of place. if you output `$finito` on a charset utf-8 site, it should look fine.

Comment: I have defined `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the master default page.

Comment: when using dd it immediately stops executing any further code (like `die()`) and only outputs what's passed to `dd()` (except you have any output/echos before dd is being called)

Answer (score 0):

your values are utf8_encoded.. try

```
echo utf8_decode($finito["D_Vannmengde_08"]);
```

Comment: laravel takes already care of en- and decoding of your db values.

Comment: oh.. haven't seen it's about laravel

Answer (score 0):

`dd($somthing)` is just used for debugging, so don't pay attention. But you need to put 
`<meta charset="utf-8">` in your view